# How to use Electrum GUI and Daemon at same time in seperate shell?

Tags: electrum, electrum-console

I'm running electrum via gui,and when I use the console the Font is so small and I haven't found a way to increase the size of console output.

Is there a way to increase the size of text ?

If not is there a way to run the GUI and also run the console in a Bash Shell separate window that I can manipulate the text format ?